# Importar atributos de classes de models de outro app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

Boa tarde galera, estou bom uma dúvida!
Estou utilizando 2 Apps no django admin

App1 = Cadastros

App2 = Controledebolsistas

Eu importei em "controledebolsistas"(App2) o model do app1, a classe "Pessoa" na classe "Bolsista", porém ele só pega o atributo "Nome" e só consigo listar o nome no Display_list no admin.py do app2.

Eu consigo listar os outros atributos da classe "Pessoa", como endereço ou data_nascimento no display_list no meu App2(Controledebolsistas)?? e como eu faço isso?

Quem puder me ajudar, eu agradeço desde ja!

**cadastros/models.py**

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):


    CPF = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 11)
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length= 45)
    Data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    Endereço = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.Nome)
```

**controledebolsistas/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from ..cadastros.models import Pessoa

  class Bolsista(models.Model):


     pessoa = models.ForeignKey("cadastros.Pessoa")  


     def __unicode__(self):
         return 'Bolsista:' + self.pessoa
```

**controledebolsistas/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from gestaobolsistas.controledebolsistas.models import Bolsista

    class BolsistaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        model=Bolsista
        list_display = ['pessoa']
        search_fields = ['pessoa']
    admin.site.register(Bolsista, BolsistaAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira bem simples de você fazer isso, é definindo um método no seu `BolsistaAdmin` que retorne essa informação. Então poderia ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from gestaobolsistas.controledebolsistas.models import Bolsista

class BolsistaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Bolsista
    list_display = ('pessoa', 'get_pessoa_cpf',)
    search_fields = ('pessoa',)

    def get_pessoa_cpf(self, obj):
        return obj.pessoa.CPF
    get_pessoa_cpf.short_description = 'CPF'

admin.site.register(Bolsista, BolsistaAdmin)
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, resolveu meu problema aqui! Muito obrigado, abraço